# Copy the content of one file and insert it in particular line in another using vim

Tags: linux, vim, command-line, copy-paste

I couldn't find a way to copy the content of one txt file and insert it to particular line for instance line number 10 in another file in vim. I was trying to do somehow do it with cat but it didn't work.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: @Barmar [vi.se]?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Completely forgot that it has its own site. :) I just used my generic "not programming" comment.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy.
Say you want to copy all content of `file1` to `file2` at the line 10.
You open `file2` with vim, move to line10: `10G`

Then just do `:r /path/to/file1` press enter.
Read

```
:h :r
```

for details.

Comment: Possibly bc this is almost surely a dupe?

Answer (score 0):

With vim bindings:

1. go to line 1
2. click `Shift-V` to enter Visual mode, selecting entire lines.
3. click `Shift-G` to go to end of file, while selecting all lines
4. click `y` to yank (copy) the entire contents created.
5. Go to the desired file:line and click `p` to paste the contents in clipboard